# Not able to select item of Flutter Dropdownbutton

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I was trying to implement dropdownbutton in a flutter project.Dropdownbutton list will be populated from api. I have fetched the list from api.

But when I select an item, it is not showing. The error message is given below

```
The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<Categories>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<List<Categories>>#09534):
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Instance of 'Categories'. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 805 pos 15: 'items == null  items.isEmpty  value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'
```

I am also adding the dropdownbutton code on the Pastebin.

https://pastebin.com/ReJPXN6D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think in your case `value: _currentItemSelected` might be null

also you should manage `FutureBuilder snapshotstate and error`

```
String _currentItemSelected = "";

FutureBuilder<List<Categories>>(
future: _fetchCats(),
builder: (BuildContext context,
AsyncSnapshot<List<Categories>> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Text(
                        snapshot.error,
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {

                   return  DropdownButton<String>(
                            isExpanded: true,
                            items: snapshot.data?.map((Categories value) {
                              return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: value.name,
                                child: new Text(value.name, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),),
                              );
                            })?.toList() ?? [],

                          onChanged: (String value) {
                            //field.didChange(value.name);

                            setState(() {
                              print(value);
                              this._currentItemSelected = value;
                            });
                          },
                            value: _currentItemSelected == "" ? _currentItemSelected = snapshot.data.first.name : _currentItemSelected,,
                            hint: Text('Event Category',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 15,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                            underline: Container(
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey))
                              ),
                            ),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Color(0xffF9B538),
                            ),
                          );
                        })

                       }
```

hope it helps..

Comment: point is I am not able to select the item from the list.Every time I select, it shows the error

Comment: this is solving my issue. I can populate the list.FutureBuilder snapshotstate has no error. Error is coming "onchange:". When I select an item from the list, it is showing error

Comment: did you try? onchange rebuld the widget so for few second snapshot will be null ,and you are returning widget without checking snapsot connection state,you shoud return widgett only when snapshot hasdata == true